# jQuery Data table is very slow with request to Server Side when click pagination many time

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used jQuery DataTable in my site that displays all the law list for our clients, I am currently using jQuery DataTable plugin for pagination, searching and sorting. It works fine except one problem Data Loading is very slow when i click on pagination many time. I am really not sure what is problem.

Cheers! Thanks in advance!

Here my website: http://law.darwinkh.org/en/legal-database

Here my code

```
if($('#legal-database').length) {
    var tableLaw = jQuery('#legal-database').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search",
            "sProcessing": "Processing...",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Processing...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
            "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
            "sEmptyTable": "No data available in table",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "First",
                "sLast":  "Last",
                "sNext":  "Next",
                "sPrevious": "Previous"
            }
        },
      "ajax": {
        "url": "http://law.darwinkh.org/en/legal-database/law-grid-data",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": {
                catid: 0 },
            "cache": false
    },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "title" },
            { "data": "year" },
            { "data": "type" },
            { "data": "slug" }
        ],
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        initComplete: function () {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the error that's shown in the console? `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: Thanks for respone I checked on console in firebug i don't see error. I just see wating request url to server.

Comment: I don't know issue is coming from jquery datatable or server side.

Comment: In my local very slowly all time when open